# Water doesn't reflect the light

Tags: reflection

So i tried make sunset animation, when i tried to make the water reflect the sun, it won't work. I don't know if it needs a GPU(because i use Integrated graphic, which is Intel HD Graphics 620) or not. Please help me. Also, i tried to search similar question, but i don't find it. Please help me.[image]

Comment: Please specify if you are using Eevee.

Answer (score 2):

Reflections do not work the same way in eevee as they do in cycles. To get proper reflections in eevee from an emissive object, you should use an irradiance volume and a reflection cubemap (Shift+A > Light Probe).

Make the probes big enough to encapsulate what you want to reflect, and then bake indirect lighting. See below:

[image: EEVEE Reflections]

Comment: Thanks, man. It helps a lot

Comment: hi, i saw a book where they only render reflection probes at one point instead of all indirect lighting, is this a thing?

Comment: Yeah - look on the right side of the image - it's the (green) button that says "bake cubemap only".